# Password expired

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle

I have a project in vb.net and Oracle database. When the user password expired in oracle is causing an oracle exeption. I handle that exception (open a ChangePassword Form and I change the password) but I am loosing the procedure that i was ready to execute when the error appeared :
Example:

```
  Try
            conn = New OracleConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = gApp.ConnectString
            conn.Open()

          'Let's say that error appears here, I want to retun here after password has been changed

            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = "Delete_Transaction"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd)
            cmd.Parameters("in_transaction_id").Value = TransactionId
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()


        Catch ex As OracleException
           'PseudoCode:  if error is PasswordExpired->open the ChengePassForm...blah,blah
           'is handled by a Error class that i have
        Finally
            If Not conn Is Nothing Then
                conn.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try
```

The main problem is that the problem can be appeared everywhere in the code, I mean different procedures, different forms etc.
So I need a generic solution. Actually I cannot even imagine a right logic to approach this?. Could anyone show me a direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a function that takes an `Action(Of OracleCommand)`.

Call the delegate in a `Try Catch` block, and, if the password changes, simply call the action again to re-run the code with the correct password.

You would call this function with a lambda expression.
Beware that everything in the lambda expression might run more than once.

Comment: I am not so familiar with delegates and lamdas expression. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Use nested try catch statements:

```
Try
    Try
        conn = New OracleConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = gApp.ConnectString
        conn.Open()

        'Let's say that error appears here, I want to retun here after password has been changed
    Catch ex1 As OracleException
       'PseudoCode:  if error is PasswordExpired->open the ChengePassForm...blah,blah
       'is handled by a Error class that i have
    Catch ex2 As Exception
        ' throw ex2 to be handled by the parent try catch
    End Try

    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "Delete_Transaction"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd)
    cmd.Parameters("in_transaction_id").Value = TransactionId
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()


Catch ex As Exception
   'PseudoCode:  if error is PasswordExpired->open the ChengePassForm...blah,blah
   'is handled by a Error class that i have
Finally
    If Not conn Is Nothing Then
        conn.Dispose()
    End If
End Try
```

Comment: The problem is that you don't know when and where exactly the error will appear.

Comment: You can add as many 'try catch statements' as you see fit.  The password error will only happen on login, and since you are handling specific errors, you should know where the errors will occur.